# How to convert trained in custom loop subclassed tf.keras.model to tflite?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, tf.keras

I have a problem with converting trained subclassed model (`tf.keras.Model`) in custom loop to TFLite.

Suppose we have small CNN architecture that use input data (`x`) and additional information that depends on batch size and other dims (`add_info`):

```py
class ContextExtractor(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = self.__get_model()

    def call(self, x, training=False, **kwargs):
        b, h, w, c = x.shape
        add_info = tf.zeros((b, h, w, c), dtype=tf.float32) 
        features = self.model(tf.concat([x, add_info], axis=-1), training=training)
        return features

    def __get_model(self):
        return self.__get_small_cnn()

    def __get_small_cnn(self):
        model = tf.keras.Sequential()
        model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
        model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

        model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
        model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

        model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
        model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

        model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
        model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

        model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
        model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

        model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())

        return model
```

I trained it in custom loop mode (using `tf.GradientTape`). It means that I didn't compile model, I just use it as it is.

Now I want to convert it to SavedModel format, because I want to port my model in TFLite. But when I run something like:

`tf.saved_model.save(model, path_to_file)`

I got warning like:
`Skipping full serialization of Keras model <ContextExtractor object at 0x7f30340bd6d8>, because its inputs are not defined.`

And, of course, my `.pb` file that I got -- super small and nothing in it.

Can anyone provide full explanation how to convert subclassed model to SavedModel? Or maybe I can convert my model to TFLite without it?